# Badge for user video upvote. "Cinematographer"

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, badges, badge-request

User will post a created video(s) as a question or answer.

Links or raw video file is accepted.

The community will decide if they think it is a quality video question or answer and up or down vote it.

The badge might be called "The Cinematographer" or just "Cinematographer" or maybe 
"Youtuber"

Comment: We already have badges for participation in particular tag, so I don't know why we need further-specialized badges for *one* particular tag.

Comment: @casperOne I assumed he was talking about a post containing an original video, as you might have on [Gaming.SE].

Comment: @TimSiteisaForum I can kind of see that now, but that's...  Difficult to get even after reading a few times.

Comment: How exactly would you determine if the user actually created the video? They could just link to any video that answers the question with no effort.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[I did not make this video, however you will watch it and then come back and upvote and accept this answer because it answers your request wholly and succinctly.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gvdf5n-zI14)

Comment: And I award you "Cinematographer" badge :P